# how to submit GET form with jstl parameter

Tags: html, jstl, form-submit

i have following form it does not show jstl parameter in url after submiting

```
<form action="Contactus.jsp?param1=${value1}" method="get">
  <input  type="submit" value="${btnregister}" id="registration-link">
</form>
```

After submitting form it only shows Contactus.jsp? and param1 disappears.
Why?

actually i want to pass language parameter to be appended to every url so that user can have idea which language is being used 
here is my updated code....

```
  <%@ page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
  <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
  <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
  <c:set var="language" value="${not empty param.language ? param.language : not empty   language ? language : pageContext.request.locale}" scope="session" />
  <fmt:setLocale value="${language}" />
  <fmt:setBundle basename="com.example.i18n.text" />
  <html lang="${language}">
  <form action="Contactus.jsp?language=${language}" method="get">
  <input  type="submit" value="${btnregister}" id="registration-link">
  </form>
```

Comment: What happens if your action="Contactsus.jsp?param1=a"?

Comment: parameter does not shows in url after submitting

Comment: Then your JSTL should not be a problem assuming you have value1 in your scope.

Comment: Not sure why, without seeing your complete code. But to pass param1 you may use <input type="hidden" name="language" value="${language}"/>

Answer (score 0):

Is ${value1} in the generated html code? If it is, there could be an issue in the servlet you're calling.